# Logging POST data from http request is good or bad practise?

Tags: http, nginx, web, http-post

We should log post data or not, if not then why?
I did not get proper answer anywhere.

Comment: This is too opinionated.  Honestly it really depends on who is looking at the logs or if anyone is auditing. Generally you don't want to log the actual POST data because if that data is sensitive you just made your clients vulnerable from a business stand point.

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to log any events containing personally identifying information (PII) or security credentials, as that makes your log storage system a greater privacy and security liability than is strictly necessary.

For this reason, people frequently avoid logging the body of POST requests, as they might contain user's email addresses, passwords, user or internal API keys, etc.

However, you may safely collect such logs if you write application-specific rules to sanitize these log messages of sensitive information.